# Clone a subfolder from git repo without the repo structure

Tags: git

I would like to clone a subfolder of this project https://github.com/veista/smartthings namely smartthings/custom_components/smartthings however all the answers of related questions keep the repo structure: my-dir/smartthings/custom_components/smartthings and I would like the following result: my-dir/smartthings(the subfolder, not the repo root)

Is it possible?

Comment: Cloning is something you do to a repository. Files are part of the working directory. Are you trying to check out a copy of a folder? Do you need to preserve the history and be able to commit back? Can you explain your requirements and expectations, and show how the things you tried did not meet them?

Comment: If it's not possible with the actual code, you could Fork the repository to edit the existing code with your own logic (and possibly add a feature to configure and send a pull request)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on some soda-straw connection or paying by the byte or something, you can also use the filtering support the main Git hosting services support and Git's core commands,

```
git clone -n --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/veista/smartthings
cd smartthings
git read-tree -um @:custom_components/smartthings
```

and to check out another commit you do `git reset --soft $thatcommit; git read-tree -um @:custom_components/smartthings`. Everything else can be worked around in similar fashion.

This is really not how Git's built to operate. In any real use it is *vastly* more efficient to just fetch the damn repo. This repo you only want a piece of is 508KB *including the checkout*; it's a 188KB download. The page load for checking answers to your question exceeds the sum total of all the data traffic you could save with this, to say nothing of the human time and effort spent on the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- clone the original repository
- apply to this local cloned repository a [`git filter-repo` command](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python-based, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md))
  It includes [path-based filtering and renaming](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_path_based_filtering):

That is:

```sh
cd local/cloned/repo
git filter-repo --path custom_components/smartthings/ --path-rename custom_components/smartthings/:/
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/<newRepo>
git push
```