Download specific folder github api
I want to download all the contents inside a Github repo. So lets say i want to download everything inside the folder "people" when i do that it only downloads the files not the other folders inside of that folder and its content. Does anyone know a way around this because i couldn't find a way. The api is limited to only downloading file not folders if im correct.
I had the idea to create a script to clone the repo and filter everything that i don't want. Yes it can work but there is for sure an easier way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+single+folder

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70429746/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+subfolder

Sparse checkout and shallow clone.
